# How can the onMouseWheel event be caught and stopped from being handled elsewhere

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to catch the `onMouseWheel` event for the whole page (for context I am doing custom scrolling) but need to stop everything else on the page handling it too. How could this be done?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should read [this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla_event_reference/wheel?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2FDOM_event_reference%2Fwheel) about variations across browsers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should call

```
event.preventDefault();
```

after processing the event.

Like this:

```
window.addEventListener("onMouseWheel", function(event) {
    // process the event for custom scrolling

    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
}, true);
```

Comment: You should also call `event.stopPropagation();` if you intend to stop the event bubbling (so that the event is really *not* handled by other event mousewheel event listeners in the tree).

Comment: @RobW Isn't window the topmost listener?

Comment: If the event was fired on an element in the body - an element with a handler for the event - then that event handler will be called *before* the event bubbles to the `window`.

Comment: He is already doing his handling in his element, as mentioned in the question.

Comment: @ATOzTOA In your example, the event is bound at bubble phase. Then, `stopPropagation()` is indeed not needed, because `window` is at the end of the tree. However, binding the event at bubble phase means that methods at a lower level in the tree can call `stopPropagation()`, which prevents your global event listener from being triggered. By binding the event to the capture phase, `stopPropagation()` **is** relevant, try this example: http://jsfiddle.net/vkpRc/

Comment: @RobW is right... addEventListener's third parameter matters here.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in jquery like this:

```
$(function(){
    $('*:not(body)').on('mousewheel',function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
});
```

Alternate solution using pure javascript:

```
var ele = document.querySelectorAll('*:not(body)');
ele.forEach(function(i){
    ele[i].addEventListener('mousewheel',function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
    },false);
});
```

Comment: He wants the solution in JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately the `.forEach` chucks up an error in IE10

Comment: `querySelectorAll` returns a `NodeList`, not an array. There is no `forEach` method for `NodeList`s. Besides, it's a terrible suggestion to loop through all elements and bind the event. Since the `mousewheel` bubbles, a single `mousewheel` event with capture flag=true will do the job as well.